# Does there exist a a general counting function related to the prime counting function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions, integers, distribution-of-primes

Does there exist a a general counting function related to the prime counting function?

Say for example I wanted all the positive integer multiples of three less than or equal to N, is there a multiples of 3 less than or equal to N counting function?

Sometimes, I might want all positive integer multiples of a product of primes, for example 15, does there exist a positive multiples of 3 and 5 less than or equal to N counting function?

Comment: If you can imagine it, it exists. It should be well defined if it simply counts whether integers have a property or not. You can see any counting function as the cumulative sum of an indicator function which is either 1 or 0 for each integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on my comment: If you can imagine it, it exists. It should be well defined if it simply counts whether integers have a property or not. You can see any counting function as the cumulative sum of an indicator function which is either 1 or 0 for each integer.

Consider an indicator function for your property $A$, $\chi_A(n)$. As you have indicated you could define a counting function $\pi_A(n)$ as [assuming we are interested in strictly positive integers]
$$
\pi_A(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \chi_A(k)
$$
interesting results related to this include a difference generating function. For primes $p_k$, and prime counting function $\pi_p(n)$
$$
\sum_{k=p_1}^\infty x^{\pi_p(k)} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (p_{k+1}-p_k)x^k
$$
in general for any counting function, for numbers $a_k$, relating to condition $A$
$$
\sum_{k=a_1}^\infty x^{\pi_A(k)} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{k+1}-a_k)x^k
$$
for example, the number counting function $\chi_n(n)=1$, gives $\pi_n(n)=n$ and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{\pi_n(k)} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1-k)x^k=\frac{x}{1-x}
$$
in this case $\pi_n(n)$ is the fastest-growing counting function and it is linearly increasing.

Consider the square indicator function $\chi_{\square}(n)$, with condition $\square(n):\sqrt{n}\in \mathbb{N}$, then we have
$$
\pi_\square(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \chi_\square(k)
$$
then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{\pi_\square(k)} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty ((k+1)^2-k^2)x^k =  \frac{3x-x^2 }{(x-1)^2}
$$
one of my favourites is $\pi_p(\pi_p(n))$ i.e. the nested prime counting function, which relates to the sequence [A073131](https://oeis.org/A073131) as
$$
\sum_{k=3}^\infty x^{\pi_p(\pi_p(k))} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (p_{p_{k+1}} - p_{p_k})x^k
$$
so we can see $\pi_p(\pi_p(n))$ **counts prime indexed primes**, such as 3, 5, 11, 17, 31, 41, 59, 67, 83, 109,... or [A006450](https://oeis.org/A006450). We can see that any strictly increasing integer sequence will have an indicator function, and therefore a counting function, and also a difference generating function. We can nest different kinds of counting functions, for example
$$
\sum_{k=3}^\infty x^{\pi_\square(\pi_p(k))} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (p_{(k+1)^2} - p_{k^2})x^k
$$
tells us $\pi_\square(\pi_p(k))$ **counts primes whose indices are square**, and this teaches us that a general chain of compositions gives
$$
\sum_{k=x}^\infty x^{\pi_{A} \circ \pi_{B} \circ \cdots \pi_{Z} \circ k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (z \circ \cdots \circ b \circ a \circ (k+1) - z \circ \cdots \circ b \circ a \circ (k))x^k
$$
and that **a composition of counting functions is also a counting function**, because this the right hand side is just a difference of terms.

**Your examples:** Positive integer multiples of three go like $3,6,9,12,...$, the indicator function could potentially be written as
$$
\chi_{m3}(n) = \bmod(1+2n^2,3)
$$
the counting function associated with this is
$$
\pi_{m3}(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor
$$
which uses notation for the floor function. We can use the concept of nesting for the multiples of 15, we have
$$
\pi_{m15} = \pi_{m3}(\pi_{m5}(n)) = \pi_{m5}(p_{m3}(n)) = \left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{5} \right\rfloor}{3} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor}{5} \right\rfloor
$$
this should count numbers divisible by $5$ whose **indices** are divisible by $3$ or vice versa.

Comment: A minor addition, but Lacking brackets to indicate scope op may also have meant "positive multiples of 3, and 5" i.e. positive multiples of 3 or 5, in which case just $\pi_{m3}+\pi_{m5}-\pi_{m15}$ by standard logic :)